# Как замедлить имитацию ввода символов selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Как замедлить имитацию ввода символов:

При использовании функции `.send_keys` вводимые предложения из переменной съедаются и пишутся не сначала, а где-то с середины

```
text_message = 'bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-blabla-blabla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla'

buf = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('im-chat-input--text')
buf.time.sleep(wait_1).set(text_message).set_value(text_message).time.sleep(wait_1).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

как написать sleep правильно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно замедлить таким образом:

```
text_message = 'bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-blabla-blabla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla'
buf = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('im-chat-input--text')

for ch in text_message:
    buf.send_keys(ch)
    time.sleep(wait_1)

buf.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```